# Converting string to integer

Tags: visualforce

I have a field Month__c which contains month values 1,2,3..12 etc. However, it is in String format. I want to use this data to plot a chart. However, since month it is a string variable, the order by makes it 1,10,11,12,2,..,9. I want to arrange it in increasing order. Please help.

Following is my controller code:

```
    public List<OpportunityData> getOpportunityData() {
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT Month__c, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol FROM User_Stats__C where Year__c = '2013' and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0 and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 GROUP BY Month__c ORDER BY Month__c];

    List<OpportunityData> oppsData = new List<OpportunityData>();
    for (AggregateResult a : result)
    {
        OpportunityData opp = new OpportunityData((String)a.get('Month__c'),
                                                  (Double)a.get('Reve'),
                                                  (Double)a.get('Gol'));    
        oppsData.add(opp);
    }
    return oppsData;
}

public class OpportunityData
{
    public Integer month { get; set; }
    public Double Revenue { get; set; }
    public Double Goal { get; set; }
    public Double Attnmnt { get; set; }        
    public OpportunityData(String mon, Double Reve, Double Gol)
    {
        month = integer.valueof(mon);
        Revenue = Reve;
        Goal = Gol;
        Attnmnt = Reve / Gol * 100;            
    }
```

Also is there a way of setting an order for this data using apex code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the data in the controller code:

First, add the `Comparable` interface to the class, to allow custom list sorting:

```
public class OpportunityData implements Comparable
{
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        return month-((OpportunityData)o).month;
    }
// Rest of code here
```

Then, sort the list before returning:

```
    oppsData.sort();
    return oppsData;
}
```

### Entire Code

```
public List<OpportunityData> getOpportunityData() {
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT Month__c, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol FROM User_Stats__C where Year__c = '2013' and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0 and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 GROUP BY Month__c ORDER BY Month__c];

    List<OpportunityData> oppsData = new List<OpportunityData>();
    for (AggregateResult a : result)
    {
        OpportunityData opp = new OpportunityData((String)a.get('Month__c'),
                                                  (Double)a.get('Reve'),
                                                  (Double)a.get('Gol'));    
        oppsData.add(opp);
    }
    oppsData.sort();
    return oppsData;
}

public class OpportunityData implements Comparable
{
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        return month-((OpportunityData)o).month;
    }
    public Integer month { get; set; }
    public Double Revenue { get; set; }
    public Double Goal { get; set; }
    public Double Attnmnt { get; set; }        
    public OpportunityData(String mon, Double Reve, Double Gol)
    {
        month = integer.valueof(mon);
        Revenue = Reve;
        Goal = Gol;
        Attnmnt = Reve / Gol * 100;            
    }
```

Comment: The `Public Class OpportunityData` in your code is repeating with same statement in my code (towards the bottom), and hence it is giving an error. Any idea?

Comment: @Robin The expectation was to modify the relevant parts of the code. I'll just copy and paste the entire code piece for you.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. This worked perfectly. I know your intention was just to add the relevant snippet of the code. Unfortunately its been only 1 week since I started with VF, so I miss out on such minor things. Thanks for the help again.